Restrict Content Pro Plugin is not receiving data from Stripe
I am currently managing a membership website utilizing the Restrict Content Pro (RCP) plugin, with payments processed through Stripe. However, I have encountered a significant issue: on the renewal date, RCP marks memberships as expired instead of automatically renewing them.
Upon investigating, I discovered that the client had not created an endpoint in the Webhook section of Stripe. I rectified this by creating the necessary endpoint and subsequently tested the system with a test user. Unfortunately, after one day, the test user’s membership was also marked as expired. Stripe showed the invoice as charged and the status as active, yet no actual charge was made to my card.
Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This seems a bug like that should be directly reported to Restrict Content Pro plugin support.

So, what exactly is your question?  Please edit your question and clarify what you're asking.  It would be helpful if you phrased your question in the form of a question. Keep in mind: we don't provide advice or guidance on this site -- questions need to be phrased in a way that one can judge whether an answer is right or wrong. Also, I'm not sure this can be answered without a minimal, reproduceable example of what you're describing, along with debugging details.

@LoicTheAztec I have already submitted my thread on RCP support forum but they don't seem to be active as 4 months earlier queries are still ananswered.

If the plugin is not maintained anymore, you should use another solution…

It looks like you’re mixing up live and test mode on stripe, just reconnect your stripe and don’t forget to click save button in RCP payments section.
